# Relationship between Zener diode voltage and knee voltage in forward bias? Also the resistance in forward bias

Tags: zener

Can somebody please help me establish a relationship between Zener diode voltage and knee voltage in forward bias? That is something where I could not find anywhere.

Comment: No such relationship as far as I know but, I’m prepared to be taught.

Comment: I notice some people call the breakdown voltage of a zener also knee voltage. I would prefer only using knee voltage for forward biased diodes.

Answer (score 1):

The 'knee' voltage of a Zener diode refers to the point where voltage drops more rapidly as current is lowered.

In **reverse** bias (ie. Zener or avalanche mode) the knee generally gets sharper and occurs at smaller current as the Zener's nominal breakdown voltage increases, but the relationship is not linear and may be different for different devices with the same nominal voltage.

Here are the V/I curves for [NXP BZX84 series](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BZX84_SER.pdf) Zeners rated from 2.4 V to 6.8 V. Below 5 V the knee becomes very 'soft' and occurs at higher current. The transition to a sharper knee above 5 V is due to the voltage regulating mechanism changing from the [Zener effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_effect) to [avalanche breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_breakdown).

[image]

At higher voltages the knee becomes sharper as it gets closer to zero, and the breakdown voltage becomes more 'ideal'. Here are the curves for BZX84 C7V4 to C24:-

[image]

In **forward** bias a Zener has an I/V curve similar to a normal silicon diode, which can be approximated with the [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation):-

$$I = I_S e^\frac{V_D}{nV_T}$$

where 
    \$I_S\$ is the scale current,
    \$V_D\$ is the voltage across the diode,
    \$V_T\$ is the thermal voltage, and
    \$n\$ is the ideality factor.

But is it right to call any place on this curve the knee? Here is the I/V curve for BZX84 series Zeners:-

[image]

This curve is obviously exponentional (as expected due to the exponential term in the equation), so if a different current scale was used the 'knee' would appear to occur at lower or higher current. However if plotted on a logarithmic current scale the curve would be almost a straight sloping line, not at all like the definite knee seen in reverse biased Zeners > 5 V.

Comment: Thanks. But I was doing an exploration on this topic and I had to prove this trend using theoretical values. Can you suggest where I can find theoretical values of breakdown voltage for different nominal voltages?

Comment: Reverse breakdown voltage is determined by Zener and/or avalanche effects, depending on the voltage. Some formulae for calculating those can be found [here](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter4/ch4_5.htm). The knee occurs at the transition from 'leakage' to 'Zener' (and.or avalanche) current at the breakdown voltage, but I have not found any way to determine the _theoretical_ 'leakage' current in Zener mode.